# There is a delay when I press the letters

Tags: windows, keyboard

My keyboard started making clicking sounds when I press the keys and now I have to hold a key for about the seconds to use it. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Turn off Filter Keys.  It's under Control Panel, Ease of Access Center.

You likely inadvertently enabled Filter Keys by holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> for 8 seconds.

Comment: What an awful "feature"...

Comment: This feature is mainly for people with muscle control / neurological diseases, and the Shift hotkey can be disabled. Accessibility shortcuts have to be... accessible.